# imported script not taking arguments

Tags: python

so ive got two scripts thats, where ive imported one into the other. script 1 is a class for the encryption function

```py
class encryption():
    def encryption(message):
    #code here isnt relevant
    def decryption(line_key):
    #code isnt relevant
```

this code works by it self but when the other code from script two tries interacting with it it get the error :

```py
TypeError: encryption() takes no arguments
```

The code for script two that interacts with script one is :

```py
x1 = entry1.get()
label4 = tk.Label(root, text = encryption.encryption(x1), font = ('helvetica' , 10 , 'bold')
```

Im really not sure what im doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't know about anyone but I think you gotta change your `class` name to capital letter at first cause it's a good practice. `class Encryption`

Comment: A methods always receives the instance as the first argument. Did you mean to declare ``encryption(self, message):``? A ``class`` seems to be the wrong abstraction though, since you appear not to be interested in having an instance. Why not use a module instead?

Comment: So there are several possible ways to "fix" this (``self``+instantiation, ``classmethod``, ...), but the general issue appears to be using a class when instances are not meaningful. We cannot really offer *the* solution until we know what you intended to do. *Why* do you have a class for this? Do you just want a namespace for the ``encryption``/``decryption`` "functions"? Do you have some other functionality not shown which actually requires a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh you have just made a typo.
you should pass self to the definition of encryption and decryption functions in your class.

```
class encryption():
    def encryption(self, message):
    #code here isnt relevant
    def decryption(self, line_key):
    #code isnt relevant
```

Comment: now its getting the error of only receiving one argument instead of two so do i have to format how i put the input in in a different way ?

Comment: I think you don't instantiate your class.  you should first instantiate an object of your class, then calling its method. i mean like this: `encrypt = encryption(); encrypt.encryption(message);`

Comment: Note that declaring the "methods" as ``classmethod`` may be more appropriate, if an instance is not meaningful. This would also allow direct usage without instantiation.